# XAML changes does not update after build

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I am creating a WPF application. I have worked on it for more than 6 months with no problem, but now, suddenly, any modifications I make on the interface, will not be updated after I build.

I am using VC# Express edition.
I tried other projects and they work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the solution and performing a full rebuild?

Clean solution is found in the "Build" menu.

Comment: Strange :) worked when I did Right Click on solution -> Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have errors, and disabled the message, telling you about these errors, then the debugger runs the old version without errors.

Comment: Worked when I did a rebuild